# Backbone Collection.fetch() returns first item null

Tags: collections, backbone.js

I'm using the following code in my view to fetch my collection from the server:

```
initialize: function () {
        _this = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success : function(collection, response) {
                _.each(response, function(i){  
                    var todo = new TodosModel({
                        id: i.id,
                        content: i.content,
                        completed: i.completed
                    });
                    // Add to collection
                    _this.collection.add(todo);
                    // Render
                    _this.render(todo);
                });
            },       
            error : function(collection, response) {
                console.log('ERROR GETTING COLLECTION!');
            }
        });
    },
```

Which seems to work - here's the output from my server:

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "one",
    "completed": false
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 4,
    "content": "two",
    "completed": true
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 5,
    "content": "tester",
    "completed": false
  }
}
```

Except for the fact that if I log out my collection there is a `null` entry in the first position:

[image]

Which then causes issues as if I add an item it takes the ID of the last element. I'm new to backbone and am hoping I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: What happens if you `_(response).each(function(o) { console.log(o) });`? Your `each` could be picking up something you're not expecting in `response`.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but here's what I'm getting: http://i.imgur.com/rxqcS.png

Comment: Here's the full code: http://sandbox.fluidbyte.org/todos/js/todos.js

Comment: I updated the `defaults` on my model to include `'content':'something'` and now the first item in the collection is `ID: null | CONTENT: something | COMPLETED: false`. How do I stop it from adding the defaults as a member of the collection?

Comment: Your app is, um, strange in various ways. For example, the collection should have added the models for you before your `success` handler is called so you don't have to do it by hand. I can give you a full critique in a few hours if you'd like; I suspect that fixing up the strangeness would make the problem go away.

Comment: A full critique would be amazing! Like I said - I'm new to Backbone so any help would be great.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that the moderators move this over to codereview.stackexchange.com since that's what this has turned into, no big deal and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my crack at a quick run through of your code. I haven't tested anything so there might be typos. I'm still not sure where the stray empty model is coming from but if you restructure your application as outlined below, I suspect the problem will go away.

The model and collection look okay so let us have a look at your view.

```
el: $('#todos'),
listBlock: $('#todos-list'),
newTodoField: $('#add input'),
//...
template: $('#todo-template').html(),
//...
events: { /* ... */ },
```

These should be okay but you need to ensure that all those elements are in the DOM when your view "class" is loaded. Usually you'd compile the template once:

```
template: _.template($('#todo-template').html()),
```

and then just use `this.template` as a function to get your HTML. I'll assume that `template` is a compiled template function below.

```
initialize: function () {
    _this = this;
```

You have an accidental global variable here, this can cause interesting bugs. You want to say `var _this = this;`.

```
    this.el = $(this.el);
```

Backbone already gives you a jQuery'd version of `el` in [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) so you don't need to do this, just use `this.$el`.

```
    this.collection.fetch({
        success : function(collection, response) {
            _.each(response, function(i) {
                var todo = new TodosModel({ /* ... */ });
                // Add to collection
                _this.collection.add(todo);
                // Render
                _this.render(todo);
            });
        },
        //...
```

The collection's [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) will add the models to the collection before the `success` handler is called so you don't have to create new models or add anything to the collection. Generally the `render` method renders the whole thing rather than rendering just one piece and you bind the view's `render` to the collection's `"reset"` event; the `fetch` call will trigger a `"reset"` event when it has fetched so the usual pattern looks like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    // So we don't have to worry about the context. Do this before you
    // use `render` or you'll have reference problems.
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    // Trigger a call to render when the collection has some stuff.
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render);

    // And go get the stuff we want. You can put your `error` callback in
    // here if you want it, wanting it is a good idea.
    this.collection.fetch();
}
```

Now for `render`:

```
render: function (todo) {
    var templ = _.template(this.template);
    this.listBlock.append(templ({
        id: todo.get('id'),
        content: todo.get('content'),
        completed: todo.get('completed')
    }));
    // Mark completed
    if(todo.get('completed')) {
        this.listBlock.children('li[data-id="'+todo.get('id')+'"]')
                      .addClass('todo-completed');
    }
}
```

Normally this would be split into two pieces:

1. `render` to render the whole collection.
2. Another method, say `renderOne`, to render a single model. This also allows you to bind `renderOne` to the collection's `"add"` event.

So something like this would be typical:

```
render: function() {
    // Clear it out so that we can start with a clean slate. This may or
    // may not be what you want depending on the structure of your HTML.
    // You might want `this.listBlock.empty()` instead.
    this.$el.empty();

    // Punt to `renderOne` for each item. You can use the second argument
    // to get the right `this` or add `renderOne` to the `_.bindAll` list
    // up in `initialize`.
    this.collection.each(this.renderOne, this);
},

renderOne: function(todo) {
    this.listBlock.append(
        this.template({
            todo: todo.toJSON()
        })
    )
    // Mark completed
    if(todo.get('completed')) {
        this.listBlock.find('li[data-id="' + todo.id + '"]')
                      .addClass('todo-completed');
    }
}
```

Notice the use of [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) to supply data to the template. Backbone models and collections have a `toJSON` method to give you a simplified version of the data so you might as well use it. The model's [`id`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) is available as an attribute so you don't have to use `get` to get it. You could (and probably should) push the `todo-completed` logic into the template, just a little

```
<% if(completed) { %>class="completed"<% } %>
```

in the right place should do the trick.

```
addTodo: function (e) {
    //...

        var todo = new TodosModel({
            id: todoID,
            content: todoContent,
            completed: todoCompleted
        });
        this.render(todo);
        todo.save();
        _this.collection.add(todo);
```

You could bind `renderOne` to the collection's `"add"` event to take care of rendering the new model. Then use the [`save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) callbacks to finish it off:

```
var _this = this;
var todo  = new TodosModel({ /* ... */ });
todo.save({}, {
    wait: true,
    success: function(model, response) {
        // Let the events deal with rendering...
        _this.collection.add(model);
    }
});
```

Again, an `error` callback on the `save` might be nice.

```
completeTodo: function (e) {
    //...
    todo.save({
        completed: todoCompleted
    });
}
```

The `save` call here will trigger a `'change:completed'` event so you could bind to that to adjust the HTML.

```
removeTodo: function (e) {
    //...
}
```

The [`destroy`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) call will trigger a `"destroy"` event on the model [and on the collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection):

> Any event that is triggered on a model in a collection will also
>   be triggered on the collection directly, for convenience. This
>   allows you to listen for changes to specific attributes in any model
>   in a collection, [...]

So you could listen for `"destroy"` events on the collection and use those to remove the TODO from the display. And destroying the model should remove it from the collection without your intervention.

```
printColl: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (todo) {
        console.log('ID: '+todo.get('id')+' | CONTENT: '+todo.get('content')+' | COMPLETED: '+todo.get('completed'));
    });
}
```

You could just `console.log(this.collection.toJSON())` instead,
you'd have to click around a little to open up the stuff in the
console but you wouldn't miss anything that way.

All the event binding for the collection would take place in your
view's `initialize` method. If you're going to remove the view then
you'd want to override the [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) to unbind from the collection
to prevent memory leaks:

```
remove: function() {
    // Call this.collection.off(...) to undo all the bindings from
    // `initialize`.
    //...

    // Then do what the default `remove` does.
    this.$el.remove()
}
```

You could also use a separate view for each TODO item but that might be overkill for something simple.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to walk through this. I've started going through the code and trying to make sense of it. I'm getting an error on underscore now that `id is not defined` and can't for the life of me find where it's coming from: http://sandbox.fluidbyte.org/todos/

Comment: Ok, figured that out - the template setup was wrong under renderOne, should be `this.template(todo.toJSON())`. Now it seems to only fetch the model defaults (see the collection print to console), and isn't rendering new items.

Comment: Sorry for the stream of comments, just so excited to finally be understanding this. I've got most of it working, the only thing that I can't get working is when you add a new item - it adds to the collection, but not the DOM. Did I miss a listener somewhere?

Comment: No worries about the comments, I just had to step out for a bit. JavaScript errors in Underscore templates can be a real PITA to figure out, the proverbial black light lighting up black on a black background problem. Sounds like you're missing a `collection.on('add', this.some_handler)` event binding.

Comment: Yup, think I got (almost) everything working, just need to do a little clean up. Thanks so much for all of your help!